# When the browser session is closed?

Tags: browser, session-cookies

Everyone knows browser closes session when window is closed... interested in this question to deep understanding how session cookie works.

I found around:

> Session cookies are never written on the hard drive and they do not collect any information from the user's computer. Session cookies expire at the end of the user's browser session and can also become no longer accessible after the session has been inactive for a specified length of time, usually 20 minutes.

So, the question is - how long are sessions in common browsers - chrome, firefox, ie, opera?

Comment: The cookie expiration is set by the server, not the browser.

Comment: really? How about JavaScript? :-)

Answer (score 0):

The session is alive as long as the browser and the server think it's alive for - for the browser, that is typically as long as the browser is open (assuming no "remember me" functionality). But the webserver may discard the session data if it thinks the client has gone away. For many web servers, this is set to be 20 minutes sin ce the previous request on that session - this is not dependant on the vendor of the browser.

Comment: so, how long browser think it's still alive?

Comment: Most session cookies are "until the browser closes"